# Adding Pre and Post Conditions using assertions

Tags: java

This is for an assignment I'm working on. One of the requirements is to add pre and post conditions to SomeClass. I'm still learning what pre and post conditions are, but more importantly, how do I implement them?

Original assignment question is here: "Write a program that shows a constructor passing information about constructor failure to an exception handler. Define class SomeClass, which throws an Exception in the constructor. Your program should try to create an object of type SomeClass and catch the exception that’s thrown from the constructor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 10:");
        int a=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter another number between 0 and 10:");
        int b=scan.nextInt();
        SomeClass testException;
        try
        {
            testException = new SomeClass(a,b);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("Exception occurred: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    public SomeClass (int a, int b) throws Exception {
        assert (a >= 0 && a <= 10) : "bad number: " + a;
        if(a<0 || a > 10){System.out.println("Try again!");}
        assert (b >= 0 && b <= 10) : "bad number: " + b;
        if(b<0 || b > 10){System.out.println("Try again again!");}
        throw new Exception("You've got an error!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is it actually expected to do?

Comment: The original assignment was posted above, but your guess is as good as mine... Basically I need to create a program that throws an argument in the constructor and has pre and post conditions. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `assert` statements will throw an `AssertionError` on failure.
However, `assert` statements must be manually enabled using JVM parameters,
as they are off by default in production code.
This won't be suitable for your assignment.

If your requirement is to throw `AssertionError`, then you can throw that explicitly:

```
public SomeClass (int a, int b) { 
    if (a < 0 || a > 10) {
        throw new AssertionError("the first param is out of valid range: " + a);
    }
    if (b < 0 || b > 10) {
        throw new AssertionError("the second param is out of valid range: " + b);
    }

    // at this point the pre-conditions have been validated
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

I omitted the `throws` clause, because `AssertionError` is not a checked exception, no need to declare it.

Lastly, in your code, the `throw new Exception("You've got an error!");` at as the last statement of the constructor will always run, even when the parameters were correct. So that statement didn't make any sense there.

Comment: The assignment has to be completed with only 2 classes; Demo3 and SomeClass. Adding an IllegalRangeException class makes sense, but 3 classes are outside of the requirements. 

However, I'm still a bit confused about pre and post conditions, does this code fulfill having them?

Comment: I updated my post a little bit. The pre-conditions are that a and b are within specified range, and those are validated. But there are no post-conditions here. A post-condition would be something like, the result of some calculation is guaranteed to be within certain range. But we don't have calculations, output, and assumptions here to write post condition assertions. Also, I replaced IllegalArgumentException with AssertionError, as probably that's what the assignment is asking for

Comment: Thank you, very much for your help!

So, for a post condition say I want to check that 'a + b = c' is within a certain range and then output either an exception or the results. Would that fulfill the post condition requirement?